# como plotar várias linhas (diferentes séries temporais) em um único gráfico - python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, gráfico, matplotlib, series-temporais

A depender de alguns filtros que aplico em meu dataset, eu gero alguns dataframes no seguinte formato:

Uma coluna com a data e outras colunas referentes a marcas do produto, trazendo os
preços.

No exemplo abaixo, temos 4 marcas de arroz (cristal, tio joão, urbano e yoki) com seus respectivos preços em cada data.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de gerar um gráfico onde o eixo X seriam as datas e haveria uma linha para cada marca (poderiam ser diferenciadas por cores).

A forma como eu sei gerar esse gráfico seria fazendo uma linha de código para cada marca, algo mais ou menos assim...

plt.plot(df['data'],df['cristal'])

plt.plot(df['data'],df['tio joão'])
...

Mas como meu dataframe é gerado a partir de alguns filtros, eu não saberei de antemão quantas marcas haverá (para o produto arroz, há 4 marcas, mas para feijão, pode haver 5 por exemplo).

Há como fazer um código que gere esse gráfico sem saber quantas colunas haverá no dataframe?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver assim:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

df.plot( figsize=(12, 15))

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).